# Java terminate a timertask using data from the task itself

Tags: java, timer, timertask

I have got the basics of how Timer and TimerTask work in Java.  I have a situation where I need to spawn a task that will run periodically at fixed intervals to retrieve some data from database.  And it needs to be terminated based on the value of the retrieved data (the data itself is being updated by other processes)

Here is what I came up with so far.

```
public class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private int count = 0;
    @Override
    public void run() {
        count++;
        System.out.println(" Print a line" + new java.util.Date() + count);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

And a class with a main method like so. For now I have trivially used a 15 second sleep to control how long the timerTask runs.

```
public class ClassWithMain {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Main started at " + new java.util.Date());
    MyTimerTask timerTask = new MyTimerTask();
    Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 0, 5*10*100);

    try {
        Thread.sleep(15000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("Main done"+ new java.util.Date());

}
```

The MyTimerTask class will become more complex with the database service calls and so on.

What I want to be able to do is, in the main class, interrogate a value returned by timerTask to dictate when to invoke timer.cancel() and terminate the process.  Right now if I try to use the count property of MyTimerTask it doesn't work.  So when I tried adding these lines in ClassWithMain

```
if (timerTask.getCount() == 5){
    timer.cancel();
}
```

it didn't stop the process.

So I'd like any direction on how I might be able to accomplish what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Why you think that timerTask.getCount() will be 5 after the Thread sleep. It most likely will be 3 because it gets incremented 3 times after 15000 mills. If you need to cancel when count is 5 then put that logic right in the run method and pass Timer to MyTimerTask so it will be accessible to the run method.

Comment: This seems a valid approach too...I never thought about passing timer to the run() method!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`private volatile int count = 0;` It is better to use 'volatile'.
try this in ClassWithMain:

```
for(;;) {
  if (timerTask.getCount() == 5) {
    timer.cancel();
    break;
  } else{
    Thread.yield();
  }
}
```